# Converting multiple list data to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If I have a list of lists like:

```
my_list = [['key1', 'key2'], [1,2], ['a','b']]
```

I want to make it into a dict where the first elements of the first list are the keys mapped to the corresponding index elements of the other dicts like:

```
my_dict = {'key1': [1, 'a'], 'key2': [2, 'b']}
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: will you always have the same number of keys as subsequent lists?

Answer (score 3):

`zip` is what you want here to obtain corresponding items from the sublists. Then you can use a dict comprehension to build the dictionary.

```
my_dict = {rec[0]: list(rec[1:]) for rec in zip(*my_list)}
# {'key1': [1, 'a'], 'key2': [2, 'b']}
```

You can leave out the `list()` call if you're OK with the dict values being tuples.

Answer (score 1):

zip-splat is the pure-python "transpose".  Then another splat in a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: v for k, *v in zip(*my_list)}
{'key1': [1, 'a'], 'key2': [2, 'b']}
```

Answer (score -2):

This should do:

```
my_dict = {r[0]: list(r[1:]) for r in zip(*my_list)}
```